# Check if MAX and rename group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following simplified data:

```
GroupName    Word    Value    isMaxInGroup

group1      foobar    100    
group1      foobar1   200     1
group2      fox       15      1
group3      snake     18    
group3      bear      25    
group3      bird      100     1
```

I have to change values in column A (`GroupName`) to the value of column B (`Word`) if this value is maximum for current group.

For example, see the next table after changes:

```
GroupName    Word    Value    isMaxInGroup

foobar1     foobar     100    
foobar1     foobar1    200    1
fox         fox        15     1
bird        snake      18    
bird        bear       25    
bird        bird       100    1
```

I've tried to use pure `VLOOKUP`, but I feel it's the wrong way and I need to use something else.
What combination of formulas I need to use, or maybe it'd better to do via `VBA`?

Comment: You'll have to do it with VBA because the group names get overwritten and thus the groups are no longer visible. Yet, if you are willing to put the `VLookUp` formula into a separate column (for example column `E`)  then you can do it with formulas only.

Comment: @Ralph Thank you. Yes, I know how to do it with vba macros. I tried to put `vlookup` in a separate column, but I don't know the right formula to get solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are to assume that the group names are in column `A` and the words in column `B` while the values are in column `C` then the following **array** formula in cell `D2` should do the trick:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(A2&MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)),$A$2:$A$11&$C$2:$C$11,0))
```

Just enter this formula into cell `D2` and then copy it down for the rest of the rows.

Please note that this is an array formula and thus must be entered using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. If entered correctly then you will see in the formula bar the following:

```
{=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(A2&MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$C$2:$C$11)),$A$2:$A$11&$C$2:$C$11,0))}
```

Note the two curved brackets around the formula. This is Excel's confirmation that this formula is evaluated as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

So, in another way, here is a simple solution in `VBA`:

```
Sub foobar()
    Dim j As Integer: j = 0
    For i = 2 to 5
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
            Cells(i, "a").Value = Cells(i, "b").Value
        Else
            Do
                j = j + 1
            Loop While Cells(i + j, "d") <> "1"
            groupName = Cells(i + j, "b").Value
            Range("a" & i & ":a" & (i + j)).Value = groupName
        End If
        j = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```